# Docker Container - source files disappearing

Tags: python, docker

A docker image I am creating and sending to a client is somehow deleting its source code 24-48 hours after it is started. We can see this by `exec` onto the running container and talking a look around.

The service is a simple flask app. The service doesn't go down as the application doesn't experience an issue but the static files it should be yielding go missing (along with everything else copied in) so we start getting 404s. I can't think of anything that would explain this (especially considering that it takes time for it to occur)

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

ARG USERNAME=calibrator
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

RUN apt-get update \
    && groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd -s /bin/bash --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME\
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    # Install open-cv packaged
    && apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgl1-mesa-glx \
    #
    ## Git
    && sudo apt-get install -y git-lfs \
    #
    ## Bespoke setup
    && apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev \
    #
    ## PostgresSQL
    && apt-get -y install libpq-dev


ENV PATH="/home/${USERNAME}/.local/bin:${PATH}"

ARG git_user
ARG git_password
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install --user git+https://${git_user}:${git_password}@bitbucket.org/****  


WORKDIR /home/calibrator

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY app app

ENV FLASK_APP=app/app.py
EXPOSE 80
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
CMD ["uwsgi", "--http", ":80", "--module", "app.app", "--callable", "app", "--processes=1", "--master"]
```

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  calibrator:
    container_name: sed-calibrator-ui
    image: sed-metadata-calibrator:2.0.3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    environment:
      - STORE_ID=N0001
      - DYNAMO_TABLE=****
      - DYNAMO_REGION=****
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=****
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=****
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=****
```

The application reads in a single configuration file and connects to a database on startup and then defines the endpoints - none of which touch the filesystem again. How can the source code be deleting itself!?

Creating a new container resolves the issue.

Any suggestions in checking the client's environment would be appreciated because I cannot replicate it.

Clients versions

- Docker Version - 18.09.7
- Docker Compose version - 1.24.0

Comment: Do you have `docker-compose` file? If yes, add it to question

Comment: @Saeed Added - I will get any changes they have made to it soon, this is mine. From what they tell me only a network adapter has been added. (definitely no volume has been mounted at the app location)

Comment: Weird. This may be off-base, but I'm wondering if there's something about the image's operating system that wants to clean up the files for some reason. Where on the filesystem are your disappearing files trying to live? And have you tried using a different base image eg. Ubuntu?

Comment: The same thing is happening to me for a few days, I have managed to reproduce the problem but still have not found the reason for the error.
reproduced in Docker version 19.03.1 and 4.1.12-124.43.4.el7uek.x86_64

I can't add all the steps as the comment is too long

I add a link to the repository where I created the test and how to reproduce it:
https://github.com/agalera/docker_test

Comment: I just tried on Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88 + OracleLinux 7.3 and the problem persists (same version on my pc and everything works (ubuntu 20.04.1))

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by updating the kernel, it also worked with an older kernel (3.10)

works:

> 4.1.12-124.45.6.el7uek.x86_64

not work:

> 4.1.12-124.43.4.el7uek.x86_64

I do not know the reason that causes it, I only know that after updating the kernel the problem was solved. I hope it is your same problem

Comment: Thank you - I've emailed this over to them and we'll try it this week. I'll post back here if that solved the problem.